# How to get the value of a field in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I need to get the value of a field; I think I am along the right lines but not quite sure this is the proper code. The "Delete Movie" button is where I am trying to get the value of that row like so:

```
value="'.$row['id'].'"
```

Can you help?

```
<?php
//connect to database
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
@mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("<b>Unable to connect to specified database</b>");
//query databae
$query = "select * from movielist";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
$row=0;
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Title</td>
     <td>Description</td>
    <td>Imdb URL</td>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>Genre</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
  </tr>";
while($row<$numrows)
{
$id=mysql_result($result,$row,"id");
$type=mysql_result($result,$row,"type");
$title=mysql_result($result,$row,"title");
$description=mysql_result($result,$row,"description");
$imdburl=mysql_result($result,$row,"imdburl");
$year=mysql_result($result,$row,"year");
$genre=mysql_result($result,$row,"genre"); ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $imdburl; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $genre; ?></td>
    <td>


<!-- Delete Movie Button -->
<form style="display: inline;" action="delete/" method="post" onsubmit="return movie_delete()">

<input type="hidden" name="moviedeleteid" value="'.$row['id'].'">

<button type="submit" class="tooltip table-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Delete trunk"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></button>
</form> 


    </td>
    </tr>
<?php

$row++;
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using it like

```
<input type="hidden" name="moviedeleteid" value="'.$row['id'].'">
```

but the question here is: how can PHP know that you are referring to a variable instead of pure HTML? PHP provide you with a very handy tool to make it explicit that you want to execute PHP code within HTML (actually *pure PHP* code don't exists as any `.php` file can contain also HTML): the `<?php` and `?>` tags.

I'm pretty sure you know what I'm talking about because you have already used them correctly. Therefore just change the above line with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="moviedeleteid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
//                                               ^^^^^ ^^^^           ^ ^^
```

What you were using was *string concatenation* which works exactly like that (with `.` to concatenate strings) but in your case was put in a HTML context.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an inline echo tag:

```
<?=$id;?>
```

This shorthand style is switched off by default, so if it doesn't work, use this instead:

```
<?php echo $id; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already extracted $id, just use it directly.

```
<input type="hidden" name="moviedeleteid" value="<?php echo $id>">
```

You cannot use PHP code between HTML tags without first specifying the start of a new piece of PHP code with the  tag.

$row is just an integer, but you are trying to use it like an array. You did not assign the content of one row to $row, but just the current row number.

Alternatively

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
{
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... I would change that a little...

```
<?php
//connect to database
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
@mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("<b>Unable to connect to specified database</b>");
//query databae
$query = "select * from movielist";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
$row=0; // ???
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Imdb URL</td>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>Genre</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
  </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    //... and so on ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?= $id; ?></td>
     <!-- and so on -->
    <td>


<!-- Delete Movie Button -->
<form style="display: inline;" action="delete/" method="post" onsubmit="return movie_delete()">

<input type="hidden" name="moviedeleteid" value="<?= $id ?>">

<button type="submit" class="tooltip table-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Delete trunk"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></button>
</form> 


    </td>
    </tr>
<?php

$row++;
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I  changed:

1. the way you iterate through the rows in `while()`
2. the way you get the field values using associative arrays
3. the way you insert the id in the rendered HTML using the PHP value tag